# How to send data over QUIC

Tags: tcp, udp

I am want to use QUIC protocol to send my own data (lets say a video). I have already done the following setup,

1- download and compiled this https://github.com/google/proto-quic
2- I have also set up the toy example. https://www.chromium.org/quic/playing-with-quic

Issue: I can only send this www.example.com page, How I can send my own data over the quic in this setup.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) project on the server side.
An alternative can be [GoQuic](https://github.com/devsisters/goquic).

Both servers should be configured to provide your own web page via QUIC (which might also contain video). QUIC works only if the connection is secure, so a certificate for a valid domain should be generated. In the example [here](https://www.chromium.org/quic/playing-with-quic) the certificate is generated for the domain www.example.org. If you want to generate a valid certificate for `https://localhost` the script that generates the certificate has to be updated accordingly.

On the client side use the last version of Google Chrome. Run Chrome from the command line as follows:

```
    google-chrome \
  --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome-profile \
  --no-proxy-server \
  --enable-quic \
  --origin-to-force-quic-on=localhost:443 \
  --host-resolver-rules='MAP localhost.org:443' \
  https://localhost
```