# How to use quic trandport rtmp data

Tags: android, quic

I want to use quic to transport rtmp data on the android,how to get some clue and link to finish it
I also search [How to send data over QUIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251357/how-to-send-data-over-quic) but it only server